# What's happending in the background when you Check-in/Publish

Tags: 2007, publishing

I can see a large file have been uploaded. Now I need to check-in/Publish. Why is it taking long time to check in since the file blob is already in the SP? Then it's finally times out.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following -

1.From your site select Site Actions - Manage Content and Structure

2.Navigate to your checked out file(s) in a directory.

3.(Optional) Multi-select files by using the checkboxes at the far left.

4.In the toolbar, select Actions - Publish.  Or, using the drop down menu for the file, select Publish.

Your file should be checked-in, approved and published all together.

Hope this helps. :)